# A finitely generated group $G$ is divisible group iff trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, alternative-proof

A group $G$ is finitely generated divisible iff $G=(1) $

Attempt: One implication is trivial.

Let's try to prove the forward implication.

I want to prove some particular cases first to get some insight for the bigger picture.

$\color{red}{\text{$G$ is finite}}$ :

Since $G$ is divisible, $\forall a\in G$ and $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$ , $\exists x\in G$ such that $x^n=a$

For $n=|G|$ , $a=x^n=1$ and  identity have $n$ th roots for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$ .

Hence $G=(1) $

$\color{red}{\text{$G$ is cyclic}}$ :

Let $G=<a>$

If $|a|<\infty$ then it boils down to the first case. Hence assume $|a|=\infty$

Since $G$ is divisible, for all $k\in\Bbb{Z} $ ,$a^k$ has $n$ th root for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$ i.e

$x^n=a^k$

Implies $a^{mn}=a^k$ (where $x=a^m$ for some $m\in\Bbb{Z}$)

Implies $a^{mn-k}=1$

Implies $a=(e) $ ( since $|a|$ divide $mn-k$)

$\color{red}{\text{$G$ is finitely generated}}$ :

Let $G=<a_1, a_2,..., a_k>$ is divisible.

For $k=1 $ , it boils down to the above case.

Suppose it is true for $k$.

To show that it is also true for $k+1$.

For $a=\Pi_{i}^{k+1}a_i^{n_i}$ , $\exists x=\Pi_{i}^{k+1}a_i^{m_i}$ such that $$(\Pi_{i}^{k+1}a_i^{m_i})^n=\Pi_{i}^{k+1}a_i^{n_i}$$

Implies $\Pi_{i}^{k}a_i^{nm_i-n_i}a_{k+1}^{{nm_{k+1}}-n_{k+1}}=1$

$\Pi_{i}^{k}a_i^{nm_i-n_i}=a_{k+1}^{-({nm_{k+1}}-n_{k+1})}$

Since $a_{k+1}^{-({nm_{k+1}}-n_{k+1})}\in <a_1,a_2,...,a_k>$ and $\Pi_{i}^{k}a_i^{nm_i-n_i}$ has $n$ th root for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$ implies $a_i=1$ for all $i\in\Bbb{N}_k$ and that implies $a_{k+1}=1$.

Hence $G=(1) $

---

Let $G$ be a finitely generated divisible group.

Since $G$ is finitely generated abelian group,$G = \mathbb{Z}^r \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$

$r=0$ implies $G$ is finite and finite divisible group is trivial.

For $r\ge 1$ , an element $(a_1, a_2,..., a_k) $ is divisible by every $n\in\Bbb{N}$ implies $a_1=0$ and $a_i\cong 0 \mod (n_i) $

Since $\Bbb{Z}$ is nt divisible, for $r\ge 1$ , $G$ can't be divisible as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I did not read your solution but your claim is false: there are infinite f.g. divisible groups.

Comment: Please give an example of a finitely generated non trivial abelian group which is divisible.

Comment: Does your definition of *divisible* include *abelian*, or did you simply forget to add that assumption? Judging from your attempt, you are only claiming this for f.g. abelian groups.

Comment: Yes. I have studied divisible group only for abelian group $[\textbf{Wikipedia}$: In mathematics, especially in the field of group theory, a divisible group is an abelian group in which every element can, in some sense, be divided by positive integers, or more accurately, every element is an nth multiple for each positive integer $ n]$

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You should not trust everything you read on Wikipedia. remember: any body can edit a Wikipedia page, no matter how little they understand the subject.

Comment: After over a year, you should already know that `<` and `>` are not delimiters, and you should use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Why don't you use the classification of finitely generated abelian groups? I assume you cannot apply the classification of divisible abelian groups, but fg abelian groups have a simple structure.

Answer (score 1):

*Guba, V. S.*, [**A finitely generated complete group**](https://doi.org/10.1070/IM1987v029n02ABEH000969), Math. USSR, Izv. 29, 233-277 (1987); translation from Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR, Ser. Mat. 50, No. 5, 883-924 (1986). [ZBL0631.20025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0631.20025).

In the paper Guba constructs infinite 2-generated divisible groups. These groups, of course, are non-abelian. Proofs are very difficult.

Comment: I have done everything about abelian groups, I am not aware about non abelian divisible group. That's why I have used the tag "Abelian group"

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You need to include your hypothesis in your posts. Tags may be useful, but they are no substitute for you actually saying what you mean.

Comment: Dear professor, you haven't criticize my approach for divisible ABELIAN group. Atleast point out my mistake.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: My answer is about general divisible groups. The claim about abelian groups is, of course correct. I did not read your proof but it strikes me as a bit too long for this problem.